# Use Regex in JS to find a particular patten in a particular spot in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm not particularly strong with Regular Expressions. Basically, I have the following string:

```
Showing 1-20 of 748 results.
```

I want to extract the `"748"`, convert it to a number, and use it for comparisons. As expected, `"Showing"`, `"of"`, and `"results"` are not expected to change, but the numbers could. I have a couple of solutions in mind. The first is using lookbehinds, but I do not believe JS supports them. The second is doing a more blunt approach, maybe finding all the numbers in the string using `match()` and taking the element at the third index in the returned array (which should be `"748"`).

Any thoughts on the best way to do this?

Comment: You should be able to figure this out yourself - look for 'of ' followed by some digits followed by ' results' and capture the digits. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the regex:

```
Showing \d+-\d+ of (\d+) results\.
```

where `\d+` in each case means to match 1 or more digits. The parentheses around the number you wanted to find is called a capture group.

So if the search string was in `str`, the resulting JavaScript might look like:

```
var resultsRe = /Showing \d+-\d+ of (\d+) results\./;
var numResults = resultsRe.exec(str);
console.log("There are " + numResults + " results.");
```

Comment: Depending on the formatting of the string in border cases this could fail. For example if it says 'Showing 18 results.'. I would not make the pattern overly restrictive.

Comment: If it says 'Showing 5 of 5 results.' then it wouldn't be in the format the OP said it would.

Comment: Thanks. I need to get more comfortable with RegEx... hopefully I'll be able to find the time soon to study up on it!

Answer (score 0):

For a simple approach you could do the following:

```
(\d+)\sresults
```

All it does is capture the integer directly before the word results.